# Linking a javascript file in wordpress fuctions.php child theme?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, load

Hi I'm trying to several js files in the functions php of my wordpress twenty twelve child theme.

Is this correct as it won't load anything? I'm trying to add this snow effect http://seb.ly/demos/JSSnow/snow3d.html http://www.jqueryrain.com/?_ol9H3hd

```
    /** Load scripts */
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse82474_load_scripts' );
function wpse82474_load_scripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('my-theme-script' ,get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/Snow.js' ,array( 'jquery' ));
    wp_enqueue_script('my-theme-script' ,get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/ThreeCanvas.js' ,array( 'jquery' ));
    wp_enqueue_script('my-theme-script' ,get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/Event.js' ,array( 'jquery' ));
}
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' ); // Load jQuery
wp_script_is( 'jquery', 'registered' ) AND wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
```

Thanks for your help

Any ideas are useful

Thanks Judi

Answer (score 2):

In what folder are the js files located? In the child theme folder? Or the parent theme folder? In the last case, you shouldn't use get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). Use get_template_directory_uri() instead ([get_template_directory_uri](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri)). get_stylesheet_directory_uri() is used to get the folder of the theme stylesheet and you need the location of the theme folder.

```
wp_enqueue_script('my-theme-script', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/Snow.js' ,array( 'jquery' ));
```

Also, you don't need to call:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
```

When 'my-theme-script' gets loaded, 'jquery' is loaded automatically as well, because 'my-theme-script' depends on 'jquery'.

Furthermore, use for every script you load a unique handle name like:

```
wp_enqueue_script('my-theme-script-snow', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/Snow.js' ,array( 'jquery' ));
wp_enqueue_script('my-theme-script-treecanvas', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/ThreeCanvas.js' ,array( 'jquery' ));
wp_enqueue_script('my-theme-script-event', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/Event.js' ,array( 'jquery' ));
```

**EDIT**

To recreate the snow effect do the following:

- In your child theme, create the folder `img` and `js`.
- In `img`, put the file `ParticleSmoke.png`.
- In `js`, put the files `Snow.js` and `ThreeCanvas.js`.
- Now, copy the following lines of code from the file ["snow3d.html"](https://github.com/sebleedelisle/live-coding-presentations/blob/master/2011/JSSnow/snow3d.html) to a file called `Snow3D.js` and put it in the `js` folder: lines 27 until 144.
- Replace the following line:

  `particleImage.src = '/img/ParticleSmoke.png';`
- into:

  `particleImage.src = img_folder + '/ParticleSmoke.png';`
- Add the following code at the end of "Snow3D.js":

  `jQuery( function() {
      init();
  } );`

In `functions.php`, add the following code. Be aware of the order of the lines:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse82474_load_scripts' );
function wpse82474_load_scripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-theme-script-threecanvas', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/ThreeCanvas.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-theme-script-snow', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/Snow.js', array( 'my-theme-script-threecanvas' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-theme-script-snow3d', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/Snow3D.js', array( 'my-theme-script-snow' ) );

    $img_folder = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/img/";

    wp_localize_script( 'my-theme-script-snow3d', 'img_folder', $img_folder );
}
```

- Your `style.css` seems to be okay.

I think that you're now good to go. Let me know!

Comment: Wow thanks Tomasz will try that out. I want to put it in my child theme itself.

Comment: Hi, Jude. Did you also already check out http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes?

Comment: Hi Tomasz Please can you post the entire code. I don't understand how to implement this as I'm more so a designer/front end developer. Thanks Judi

Comment: Hi Tomasz I've managed to link the script ok but nothing has loaded. No snowflakes in sight :(

Comment: I need to know the following. What did you put in Event.js? In your child theme folder: do you have the folder "img" and in "img" the file "ParticleSmoke.png"?

Comment: It seems that you have to make some modifications to the js-code to make the snow-library work in WordPress. It is also important to load the js-files in the correct order for the snow to work. I have edited my answer and included the code and the steps to follow. The code works on my system as child theme in WordPress. So, I hope it will work in your theme as well. For now, I assume that your "style.css" is correct.